# Import related_skus in magento 2.3.5 problem

Tags: import, importexport, related-products, product-import

After upgrading Magento from 2.1.7 to 2.3.5, when making a manual products import through the admin, the related products are not attaching to the products, no errors are being shown.

I've tried importing a CSV in a the same format as the output of the manual admin products export CSV.

The related products column is "related_skus".